# Trying to Get Coinbase API to work

Tags: php, composer-php, coinbase-api

I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with the below code to work with the Coinbase API.  I have Composer installed with the Coinbase dependency.  Previously I was getting an error that the Coinbase class was not installed, which I figured out was because of the path.  I no longer get any error but the code is not executing.  Can anyone help?

```
    <?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/usr/bin/vendor/autoload.php';
    use coinbase\coinbase;

    //I've tried to run it both with and without the following 3 lines   of code with no difference
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $apiKey = 'XXX';
    $apiSecret = 'XXX';

    $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
    $client = Client::create($configuration);

    $account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();
    echo 'Account name: ' . $account->getName() . '<br>';
    echo 'Account currency: ' . $account->getCurrency() . '<br>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the examples on [the Coinbase repository](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php), you've got a namespacing issue. PHP can't find the Configuration or Client classes.

```
<?php

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
```

at the top of your file will resolve it. After that, read http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  That didn't do it unfortunately.  Going to check out those links